# Copying data from rows in the same table if it meets multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks this

| ID | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 01/01/2020 |
| 101 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 01/03/2020 |
| 101 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  | 01/05/2020 |
| 101 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 01/07/2020 |
| 201 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 02/02/2020 |
| 201 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 02/04/2020 |
| 201 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  | 02/06/2020 |
| 201 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 02/08/2020 |

What I need to do is change the **Date** column for **ID = 201** so that it matches **ID=101**. Columns **C1:C4** are used to identify the rows. So for example the last row with the **Date** = 02/08/2020 should be changed to 01/07/2020 as both their **C1:C4** are the same.

Column **C4** can have null values but other 3 columns will not be null. For every record in **ID=101**, there will be a corresponding record in **ID=201** with same values for **C1:C4**. Every combination of **C1:C4** will be unique.

I tried looking for examples with SQL UPDATE statements but could not find one that matched my case so any help would be appreciated! Thank you

UPDATE:
The following code worked to deal with the Null values

```
set t2.date = t1.date
from t t1 join t t2
ON CONCAT(t1.c1,t1.c2,t1.c3,t1.c4) = CONCAT(t2.c1,t2.c2,t2.c3,t2.c4)
where t1.id = 101 and t2.id = 202
```

Comment: `UPDATE` with `JOIN`, to handle nullables, subquery with `INTERSECT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `update` with `join`.  One method is:

```
update t2
    set t2.date = t1.date
    from t t1 join
         t t2
         on t1.c1 = t2.c1 and t1.c2 = t2.c2 and t1.c3 = t2.c3 and t1.c4 = t2.c4
    where t1.id = 101 and t2.id = 202;
```

If `c4` can be `NULL`,

```
update t2
    set t2.date = t1.date
    from t t1 join
         t t2
         on t1.c1 = t2.c1 and t1.c2 = t2.c2 and t1.c3 = t2.c3 and
            (t1.c4 = t2.c4 or t1.c4 is null and t2.c4 is null)
    where t1.id = 101 and t2.id = 202;
```

Comment: Thanks! This only worked for those rows where C4 was not null. So I changed the ON statement to ON CONCAT(t1.c1,t1.c2,t1.c3,t1.c4) = CONCAT(t2.c1,t2.c2,t2.c3,t2.c4) and that seemed to do the trick!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thought you would know well enough to use this syntax for nullables: `on exists (select t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3, t1.c4 intersect t2.c1, t2.c2, t2.c3, t2.c4)`.

Comment: @ponnob That is going to be very slow.as it won't use indexes

Comment: @Charlieface . . . This will use an index on `(c1, c2, c3)` directly and will make use of other columns if they are in the index.

Comment: But if `c4` is a key column it won't use it for lookup, whereas my solution does.